# Generating Java code from transformation JSON to a XML

Tags: java, json, xml

I wonder do you now any program that can generate for me a Java code from transformation JSON to a XML? In Altova MapForce there is such a possibility, but unfortunately when I want use it, it returns me an Error:

*Altova_Hierarchical_JSON.mfd: Mapping validation failed - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    Altova_Hierarchical: JSON components are not supported for Java.
    The output component Altova_Hierarchical has no output file name set. A default file name will be used.*

The second thing, that is important for me, is capabilities to create graphic mapping between JSON and XML like example below shows: [image]

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I tried Altova MapForce and Liquid XML 2015 Disigner Editor but I'm new on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
<anyxml>data</anyxml>
```

Output:

```
{
  "anyxml": "data",
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```